# R.app does not appear in application folder after installing R-3.4.0

Tags: r, macos, failed-installation

I am working in a MacBook Pro (15 inches, mid 2010), OSX El Capitan (10.11.6), 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

Today I tried to update from R-3.3 to R-3.4.0. I downloaded the R-3.4.0.pkg from https://cran.r-project.org/ site. After downloading I checked the MD5 checksum for the R-3.4.0.pkg image and it was the same than in the r-project website. I executed the file by double-clicking and everything appear to work fine, at the end it said that everything was installed with no problem.

The problem I have is that the old R.app was removed from my application folder but the new (R-3.4.0) does not appear in the application folder either.

I tried to download and install the GNU Fortran 6.1 and then reinstall R but nothing changed.

I tried to look for a solution in google and this forum but did not find any clue of what to do. I hope I am not missing any stupid detail or making a rookie mistake.

Thanks for your help,

Alfonso

Comment: Can you launch `R` by typing it in a terminal? If the installation was successful, I do not see how the application cannot be present.

Comment: It launches in the terminal ??? I tried several rounds of installing R-3.4.0 and R-3.3.3 (the one I had installed before) but the R.app still does not appear. I also tried the usual restart, wait, leave the room...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the R.app from http://r.research.att.com/ I got there from the r-project website.

I chose "Mac OS X GUI rev. 7362 for R 3.4.x el-capitan-Debug.dmg" instead of "Mac OS X GUI rev. 7362 for R 3.5.x    el-capitan-Debug.dmg" since to the best of my knowledge there is no R-3.5 available yet.

I do not understand why the app did not install directly from R-3.4.0.pkg but apparently this works. I leave this answer just in case is useful for someone.

Thanks for the comments!

Alfonso